# Is there a tool to remotely manage Hyper-V from a Windows XP/2003 machine?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, hyper-v

My team has a fairly significant dependency on virtual machines, and we're currently looking to add Hyper-V support in addition to our current solution using Virtual Server 2005 (value adds mainly being x64 and multi-core VMs).  The majority of our team members, however, are still running on Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP, and might not be in the mood to upgrade to Windows Server 2008 x64.

As such, I'm trying to find how we can provide a pool of Hyper-V machines that are easily available for these users.  For Windows Vista, Server 2008, and Win7, I've found tools for remote Hyper-V role management, which allows the remote user to use the VMC tool locally for a remote VM host.  I haven't been able to find anything for older versions of Windows; is there a RSAT tool (or similar) for downlevel Windows OSs to interact with newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried VMM (System Center Virtual Machine Manager)?  There is cost involved here but it may be worth it for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, because all development for XP has ended, there won't be a tool built or backported for Hyper-V management.

You could build a VM with Win7 for Virtual PC that will run on Xp.

Comment: Whilst Microsoft have ended all development for XP, doesn't mean some third party won't create something.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V Management Console might be what you are looking for.  It is not free though.

http://www.utharam.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into Remote Desktop/Terminal Services...

In order to manage the guests within the Hyper-V Management Console, they could TS/RDP into a Vista/W2K8 box that has the management tools, and manage from there.  In order to work within the guest VMs, they could simply TS/RDP into the guest (they wouldn't even know the guest was running as a VM).